# How to send common header for auth in flassger (python swagger)

Tags: python, flask, swagger, swagger-ui

Currently, I am using this type of docstring with Flassger which works fine:

```
"""End Point to create something
  ---
  parameters:
    - name: body
      in: body
      type: string
      required: true
    - name: token
      in: header
      description: an authorization header
      required: true
      type: string
  responses:
    200:
      description: Some description
  """
```

And I am able to send the request from ui like this:

[image]

But I need to make the token parameter global on this page, so that the user only need to fill this just once. What do I need to do to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

All you need to do is define the authorization token in the api definitions.
Try something like this:

```
  securityDefinitions:
  Token:
   type: apiKey
   name: Token
   in: header
```

And then put this code in the endpoint you want to secure with the token:

```
 security:
 -Token: []
```

In your example:

```
  parameters:
  - name: body
   in: body
   type: string
   required: true
   security
   - Token:[]
   responses:
     200:
      description: Some description
```

If you want to secure all the endpoints with the token do like this:

```
securityDefinitions:
  Token:
   type: apiKey
   name: Token
   in: header
security
   - Token:[]
```